# how to securely store encryption keys in android?

Tags: java, android, security, encryption, keystore

I want to know how to securely store **encryption key** in Android? What is the best scenario to protect encryption and secrete keys?

Comment: Are you taking about encrypting something on disk, or an encrypted file being stored with your app?  In the first case, create the key at runtime and put it in the Keystore.  In the second case-  do not put the key in the app.  The best thing to do is download it from the server, but doing so still leaves a window for intercept.  Really both do, if someone is trying hard enough they will get it.  The best thing to do is not put any information on the client phone you don't want the user to be able to see.

Comment: please give me an example of storing key in keystore

Comment: Are you asking about encryption keys to send data to the server or  other users (then you can store safely an assymetric public key in your apk or download it), a local encryption key to encrypt/decrypt data in your device, or do you want to encrypt the communication channel with your server?

Comment: I'm asking abut local data encryption key.

Comment: Then use [Android Keystore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore).  It is designed for this purpose. What are you looking for with your question? a tutorial? some examples?

Comment: Android Keystore will not work below API level 18.

Comment: I suggest to include this relevant info in your question. For Android <18, are you worried about root level access to the device? No>Generate a random encryption key and store it in SharedPreferencences. Yes> Request a password to the user, derive a encryption key from the password, and store it in SharedPreferences. Drawback: you need to prompt for the password when application starts

Comment: @pedrofb, SharedPreferences can be access by root privilege user.

Comment: Sorry, I have written too fast. In the second case, the encryption key does not need to be stored in the SharedPreferences because it is calculated each time when the application is started using the password

Comment: According to your second case, we need to store password instead of an encryption key. So, raised the same question: **How to securely store password?**

Comment: The password is not stored. It is requested to user each time the application starts. Nobody can derive the real encryption key because the password it is only known by the user

Answer (score 54, accepted):

From your comments, you need to encrypt data using a local key for current Android versions and the old ones

[Android Keystore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore) is designed to generate and protect your keys. But it is not available for API level below 18  and it has some limitations until API level 23.

You will need a random symmetric encryption key, for example AES. The AES key is used to encrypt and decrypt you data. I'm going to summarize your options to generate and store it safely depending on Android API level.

- **API Level < 18: Android Keystore not present**. Request a password to the user, derive an encryption key from the password, The drawback is that you need to prompt for the password when application starts. The encryption key it is not stored in the device. It is calculated each time when the application is started using the password
- **API Level >=18 <23: Android Keystore available without AES support**. Generate a random AES key using the default cryptographic provider (not using AndroidKeystore). Generate a RSA key pair into Android Keystore, and encrypt the AES key using RSA public key. Store encrypted AES key into Android SharedPreferences. When application starts, decrypt the AES key using RSA private key
- **API Level >=23: Android Keystore available with AES support**. Generate a random AES key using into Android Keystore. You can use it directly.

To encrypt to can use `AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding` algorithm. It requires also a random initialization vector (IV) to encrypt your data, but it can be public.

Alternatives:

- **API level >14: Android Key Chain**: KeyChain is a system-wide credential storage. You can install certificates with private keys that can be used by applications. Use a preinstalled key to encrypt/decrypt your AES key as shown in the second case above.
- **External token**: The protected keys are not stored in the device. You can use an external token containing a private/public key pair that allows you to encrypt the AES key. The token can be accesed using bluetooth or NFC

Comment: Thanks for the sharing useful android cryptography information.

Comment: Thank you for the exhaustive answer!
Speaking about API Level ">=18< 23" can we avoid storing AES key in SharedPreferences by simply using RSA Private Key part as a symmetric key?

Comment: @southerton, I think you can get a sufficiently secure AES secret applying a key derivation function like HKDF to the RSA key or just hashing it (SHA256 will provide 32 random bytes). Check out the discussion of this post https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/50118/derive-a-secret-from-an-rsa-private-key

Comment: @pedrofb looking at the documentation https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#SupportedCiphers we can see that "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding" is not supported below API 23, then how can we use it below API 23?

Comment: @rahulsahni, it is not supported by `AndroidKeyStore` provider, but you can still use AES with the default cryptographic provider

Comment: hi. why you are generating AES key below 23? you can encyrpt password with public key and decrpyt with private key directly . Is it not safe to use rsa keys directly?

Comment: @ahmetvefa53,because RSA encryption is limited by the size of the key. An AES key is generated for symmetric encryption, which is also much faster, and the AES key is encrypted with the RSA

Comment: @pedrofb I could not understand that  "RSA encryption is limited by the size of the key"?

Comment: my password configuration is max 10 chars.Can ı use rsa directly?

Comment: See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33434/rsa-maximum-bytes-to-encrypt-comparison-to-aes-in-terms-of-security _With the commonly used "v1.5 padding" and a 2048-bit RSA key, the maximum size of data which can be encrypted with RSA is 245 bytes. No more._ RSA is enough for 10 characters

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want [EncryptedSharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences) or [EncryptedFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedFile). Both of these use the [AndroidKeyStore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore). The code snippets below actually answer the question "How do I use the AndroidKeystore to encrypt a file or store a cryptographic key?"

Make sure to include `implementation "androidx.security:security-crypto:1.0.0-rc02"` in your app `build.gradle` file.

from [EncryptedSharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences):

> An implementation of [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) that encrypts keys and values.

```
String masterKeyAlias = MasterKeys.getOrCreate(MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC);

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
  "secret_shared_prefs",
  masterKeyAlias,
  context,
  EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
  EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
);

// use the shared preferences and editor as you normally would
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
```

You could store an encryption key like this:

```
// generate random symmetric key
KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
keyGen.init(256);
SecretKey symkey = keyGen.generateKey();


String alias = "your encryption key";

// store symmetric key
byte[] encodedSymmetricKey = symkey.getEncoded();
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
String base64EncodedSymmetricKey = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(encodedSymmetricKey));
edit.putString(alias, base64EncodedSymmetricKey);
edit.commit();

// retrieve symmetric key
String raw = sharedPreferences.getString(alias, null);
byte[] symKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(raw);
SecretKeySpec spec = new SecretKeySpec(symKey, "AES");

assert(spec.equals(symkey));

// use your encryption key
```

Although it would be much better to use [EncryptedFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedFile).

---

from [EncryptedFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedFile):

> Class used to create and read encrypted files.

```
String masterKeyAlias = MasterKeys.getOrCreate(MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC);

File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "secret_data");
EncryptedFile encryptedFile = EncryptedFile.Builder(
  file,
  context,
  masterKeyAlias,
  EncryptedFile.FileEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM_HKDF_4KB
).build();

// write to the encrypted file
FileOutputStream encryptedOutputStream = encryptedFile.openFileOutput();

// read the encrypted file
FileInputStream encryptedInputStream = encryptedFile.openFileInput();
```

**note:**
The master key, once created, is constant. So even after a phone reboot your app will still be able to encrypt/decrypt the file.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot place the encryption key inside your apk file. You may want to keep it in a remote server and decrypt using server. Or you may make it difficult for others by encoding the key and keeping it in non-obvious places. But there's no bullet proof solution for this.

Comment: what about **androidKeyStore** ?

Comment: If the encryption key can be a random String generated at runtime, you can use KeyStore. But it can be read from a device with root access if stored persistently.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to securely save your private api keys into code. But you can use
NDK to securely save private keys. It is not trivial to get key from NDK. [Secue Key With NDK Example](https://androidsecurity.info/2016/12/15/storing-your-secure-information-in-the-ndk/)

Comment: C++ on the other hand can’t be decompiled but can be **disassembled**, which is slightly less trivial than java. its also not secure :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android Keystore system to store and retrieve sensitive information.
Read this 5 minute article to understand how it works.
[Using the Android Keystore system to store and retrieve sensitive information](https://medium.com/@josiassena/using-the-android-keystore-system-to-store-sensitive-information-3a56175a454b)

Comment: Where I can save the IV  ?

Comment: As far as my experience, you need to have the same IV to decrypt. So, when encryption does, you will have IV, convert it to Base64 encoding and attach with the encrypted data by putting some separator and store your final encrypted text, So when you decrypt, you will have Base64 encoded IV attached with the text you encrypted, split that with the separator you put during encryption and you will get IV in Base64 encoded form, decode it and use for decryption.